# how to use one of the parameters of jdbc response from sql query into payload in json(request parameter) for web service testing

Tags: soapui

I am getting xml response from sql(jdbc) in soap ui open source. 
And now, I want to use one of the parameters as input request(json payload) for web service automation.

lets say, in sql response has :--id, roll no, name, address, phone no.
in json payload, i want to pass roll no. as input(taken from sql response).
Please help

Thanks in advance

Comment: JUst extract the required data and save it into custom property and use that value in the following requiest. Refer documentation here https://www.soapui.org/scripting-properties/property-expansion.html

Comment: Thanks for highlighting this. But i am afraid, i dont know the extraction work. the way i can extract node and its value from jdbc xml response and put it in custom property. Please enlighten as i am just learning automation by myself.

Comment: Refer: https://community.smartbear.com/t5/SoapUI-Open-Source/How-to-use-value-from-jdbc-response-into-the-json-payload-for-a/m-p/200053#M30245